# Using electron api in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, electron

I want to use electron from typescript.
I installed `dt~gihub-electron` and node type definitions via typings.
But when I try to compile I get the following error:

> typings/globals/github-electron/index.d.ts(5,29): error TS2304: Cannot
>   find name 'NodeJS'.

here is my tsconfig.json:

```
    {   
     "compilerOptions": {
       "target": "es5",
       "outDir": "dist/frontend/app",
       "module": "system",
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "sourceMap": true,
       "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
       "experimentalDecorators": true,
       "removeComments": false,
       "noImplicitAny": false
     },
     "exclude": [
       "node_modules",
       "typings/globals"
     ],
     "files": [
     "typings/index.d.ts"
     ]
    }
```

and typings/index.d.ts:

```
/// <reference path="globals/es6-shim/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/node/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="globals/github-electron/index.d.ts" />
```

thank you for any help.

Comment: Try removing typings/globals from exclude

Answer (score 1):

I cam up with as solution myself.
It was the case that I installed the node typings from the env source and the electron typings form the dt source.
I uninstalled the node typings and reinstalled them from the dt source, and now it is working.
But I am a little bit confused, because the d.ts files from both souces seem to look the same, and as far as I know only the d.ts files matter.